# Swift Linking Error Arm V7

Tags: xcode, swift, error-handling, ld

I have been trying for hours to fix this build error.
None of the advice from the dozens of threads I've read has fixed this error. What can I do?

> "ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see >invocation)"
>
> > Ld /Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Intermediates/The-Talon.build/Release-iphoneos/The-Talon.build/Objects-normal/arm64/The-Talon normal arm64
> >         cd /Users/yanayrosen/Desktop/Talon-Iphone-master
> >         export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
> >         export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
> >         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/yanayrosen/Desktop/Talon-Iphone-master/../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/../iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/yanayrosen/Desktop/Talon-Iphone-master -F/Users/yanayrosen/Desktop/Talon-Iphone-master/Talon -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/../iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Intermediates/The-Talon.build/Release-iphoneos/The-Talon.build/Objects-normal/arm64/The-Talon.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Intermediates/The-Talon.build/Release-iphoneos/The-Talon.build/Objects-normal/arm64/The_Talon.swiftmodule -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -lz.1 -lsqlite3 -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Intermediates/The-Talon.build/Release-iphoneos/The-Talon.build/Objects-normal/arm64/The-Talon_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/yanayrosen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The-Talon-ebdutvfwgeagoxgpqbewfvfjaksq/Build/Intermediates/The-Talon.build/Release-iphoneos/The-Talon.build/Objects-normal/arm64/The-Talon"

Comment: You just need to clean your project **cmd+shift+k** and then try to run .

Comment: I have and I still get the same error. I have also restarted Xcode and cleaned multiple times and still get the same error. If I add AppDelegate to build phases compile, then I get an unknown directory error.

Comment: dose your other than this project running fine ? or the error is for all ?

Comment: The only error is in the app delegate file, I can't even build my app.